# Why is my iPod nano reading everything out loud and functioning abnormally?

Tags: ipod-nano

I just reset my iPod nano 7th gen via iTunes to remove some broken tracks and then resynced it, and when I unplugged it after disconnecting it, everything was quite broken.

First of all (with a headset plugged in) the iPod is reading *everything* out loud....*screen dim, music, double tap to open*, etc. But then, in conjunction with this, I can't control the screen like normal...you have to double-tap to open anything and I can't swipe side to side to get to settings so I can't try to change whatever mode this is. When you slide a finger over the icons, a little selection square moves over them with you.

What's going on?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's in VoiceOver mode (an accessibility feature). I don't have an iPod nano, but on iOS, under General, there's an Accessibility menu where you can turn it off.

Answer (score 2):

You can fix it, but its a bit of a pain.

1. Swipe left using two fingers till you get to Settings and double tap.
2. Double tap General.
3. Fiddle with it till you get down to Accessibility and Double tap.
4. Double tap VoiceOver.
5. Turn off VoiceOver.

Should work fine from there. I had the same problem with my 6th Gen Nano.

Answer (score 0):

You can swipe to the next screen by using two fingers instead of one, and then move the selection box to whichever element you want to choose and open it by double-tapping.